# to whether + bare infinitive + or to verb

Tags: verbs, bare-infinitive, whether

I wanted to see whether this phrase is grammatically correct or not. I want to use it in my PhD thesis.

"Customers have more freedom to whether buy a new product or to get their money back. "

Comment: Customers have more freedom **as** to whether buy a new product or to get their money back.

Comment: "Customers have more freedom whether to buy a new product or get their money back". Though 'whether..or' is used to talk about two or more possibilities, it has an implication of doubt sometimes. I prefer "Customers have more freedom either to buy a new product or get their money back".

Comment: These options don't make sense to me.  Customers always have the freedom to buy a new product; perhaps they are exchanging a defective product for a different one instead of getting their money back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard English correlative conjunction is:
    either...or

"whether " in your sentence is misused.

```
 ...either buy a new product or get their money back.
```